# Syntax highlighting of javascript file in an ASP.NET MVC view?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, view, syntax-highlighting

I have an ASP.NET MVC website which has a particular javascript file that needs to be run through the razor parser to render some `@Url` values. I have a controller action, named `public ActionResult Javascript()` which simply returns javascript.cshtml as a partial view.

This all works fine, except that I lose syntax highlighting on the javascript. Is there a way to enable the razor parser on custom file extensions so I can rename my view to javascript.js and get that syntax highlighting back? Failing that, is there any other way I can force the view file to syntax-highlight as javascript when it's not wrapped in `<script>` tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are better ways to reference controller actions from Javascript than baking in `@Url.Action(...)` calls. For example:

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/08/18/calling-asp-net-mvc-action-methods-from-javascript.aspx